Error en el paquete SPACECAP de R
Obtengo el error

"Error in if (runif(1) < exp(sum(rowsum(llvector.new - llvector, indid)[z ==  :    valor ausente donde TRUE/FALSE es necesario"

en el paquete SPACECAP de R, el error aparece al querer ocupar un archivo con una base de datos, ya lo intenté con otras bases similares y sí corre

¡Hola Diego! Para poder ayudarte mejor es importante que puedas poner un ejemplo reproducible de qué comando estás ejecutando para obtener el error. Esto facilitará que te puedan ayudar.
